# Keyboard shortcut to close Chrome Developer Tools on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut to close Developer Tools on on Google Chrome on a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

It's like opening it: `ALT`+`CMD`+`I`